# Cropping GeoTIFF to just the map

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

Given a GeoTIFF that has a map, extra textual descriptions of rock, and cross-sections all in one .tif file, is there an automatic way to crop the GeoTIFF to just the map? A programmatic solution in Python or one that uses GDAL would be preferable.

Comment: Can you elaborate your request, please? What do you mean with "crop the GeoTIFF to just the map"? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, yes: I downloaded from NGMBD the GeoTiff available at [this](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/Prodesc/proddesc_11014.htm) site. I would like to crop out all text, cross section and relative age information, leaving only the map without any whitespace on its edges.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a GIS like QGIS to clip the image. You can select the clipping region in a GUI that way. All it does is run a `gdal_translate` command in the background, but the interactive decision on what coordinates to supply for the bounding box makes it easy.

Raster>Extraction>Clipper...